# Check the existence of two files in a directory

Tags: perl

I want check if files A or B are present in a directory.
The user should be informed whether neither,
either or both files are present.

I found that it can be done using glob function in perl:

```
if ( glob("*.file") ) {
    # At least one file matches "*.file"
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to do and in what way the code you showed isn't enough.

Comment: See file test operators in [`perldoc -X`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: @zwol, the code works but i want the filenames of the files which exist.

Comment: @Yash you said you want to check if file A is present, then you know the name is "A"?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is resolved now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you assign the return value of `glob` to a list, and then use the size of that list:

```
my @files = glob '*.file'
print 'found ' . @files . " files\n";
```